# Polish chars in gedit (Fedora 18)

Tags: fedora, character-encoding, gedit

I locked my Fedora18 computer (set to Polish). Later I couldn't log in (password was accepted, but I didn't see my desktop). I used `pkill -KILL -u tymon` command in root mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd>).

After this, I didn't see (my native) Polish characters in `gedit` (I see only "bushes"). I don't why. I didn't install any update. Restart didn't help.

What should I do?

PS : 
When I wrote `gedit --list-encodings` there wasn't utf-8 :

```
ISO-8859-1
ISO-8859-2
ISO-8859-3
ISO-8859-4
ISO-8859-5
ISO-8859-6
ISO-8859-7
ISO-8859-8
ISO-8859-9
ISO-8859-10
ISO-8859-13
ISO-8859-14
ISO-8859-15
ISO-8859-16
UTF-7
UTF-16
UTF-16BE
UTF-16LE
UTF-32
UCS-2
UCS-4
ARMSCII-8
BIG5
BIG5-HKSCS
CP866
EUC-JP
EUC-JP-MS
CP932
EUC-KR
EUC-TW
GB18030
GB2312
GBK
GEORGIAN-ACADEMY
IBM850
IBM852
IBM855
IBM857
IBM862
IBM864
ISO-2022-JP
ISO-2022-KR
ISO-IR-111
JOHAB
KOI8R
KOI8-R
KOI8U
SHIFT_JIS
TCVN
TIS-620
UHC
VISCII
WINDOWS-1250
WINDOWS-1251
WINDOWS-1252
WINDOWS-1253
WINDOWS-1254
WINDOWS-1255
WINDOWS-1256
WINDOWS-1257
WINDOWS-1258
```

PPS :
`Journaltclt -b` gives me :

```
-- Logs begin at nie 2013-05-12 15:57:17 EDT, end at nie 2013-05-12 14:01:04 EDT. --
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain systemd-journal[454]: Allowing runtime journal files to grow to 196.8M.
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain systemd-journald[96]: Received SIGTERM
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain kernel: SELinux: 2048 avtab hash slots, 96259 rules.
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain kernel: SELinux: 2048 avtab hash slots, 96259 rules.
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain kernel: SELinux:  9 users, 15 roles, 4389 types, 246 bools, 1 sens, 1024 cats
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain kernel: SELinux:  83 classes, 96259 rules
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain kernel: SELinux:  Permission attach_queue in class tun_socket not defined in policy.
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain kernel: SELinux: the above unknown classes and permissions will be allowed
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain kernel: SELinux:  Completing initialization.
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain kernel: SELinux:  Setting up existing superblocks.
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain kernel: SELinux: initialized (dev sysfs, type sysfs), uses genfs_contexts
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain kernel: SELinux: initialized (dev rootfs, type rootfs), uses genfs_contexts
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain kernel: SELinux: initialized (dev bdev, type bdev), uses genfs_contexts
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain kernel: SELinux: initialized (dev proc, type proc), uses genfs_contexts
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain kernel: SELinux: initialized (dev tmpfs, type tmpfs), uses transition SIDs
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain kernel: SELinux: initialized (dev devtmpfs, type devtmpfs), uses transition SIDs
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain kernel: SELinux: initialized (dev sockfs, type sockfs), uses task SIDs
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain kernel: SELinux: initialized (dev debugfs, type debugfs), uses genfs_contexts
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain kernel: SELinux: initialized (dev pipefs, type pipefs), uses task SIDs
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain kernel: SELinux: initialized (dev anon_inodefs, type anon_inodefs), uses genfs_contexts
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain kernel: SELinux: initialized (dev devpts, type devpts), uses transition SIDs
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain kernel: SELinux: initialized (dev hugetlbfs, type hugetlbfs), uses transition SIDs
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain kernel: SELinux: initialized (dev mqueue, type mqueue), uses transition SIDs
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain kernel: SELinux: initialized (dev selinuxfs, type selinuxfs), uses genfs_contexts
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain kernel: SELinux: initialized (dev sysfs, type sysfs), uses genfs_contexts
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain kernel: SELinux: initialized (dev securityfs, type securityfs), uses genfs_contexts
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain kernel: SELinux: initialized (dev tmpfs, type tmpfs), uses transition SIDs
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain kernel: SELinux: initialized (dev tmpfs, type tmpfs), uses transition SIDs
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain kernel: SELinux: initialized (dev tmpfs, type tmpfs), uses transition SIDs
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain kernel: SELinux: initialized (dev cgroup, type cgroup), uses genfs_contexts
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain kernel: SELinux: initialized (dev cgroup, type cgroup), uses genfs_contexts
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain kernel: SELinux: initialized (dev cgroup, type cgroup), uses genfs_contexts
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain kernel: SELinux: initialized (dev cgroup, type cgroup), uses genfs_contexts
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain kernel: SELinux: initialized (dev cgroup, type cgroup), uses genfs_contexts
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain kernel: SELinux: initialized (dev cgroup, type cgroup), uses genfs_contexts
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain kernel: SELinux: initialized (dev cgroup, type cgroup), uses genfs_contexts
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain kernel: SELinux: initialized (dev cgroup, type cgroup), uses genfs_contexts
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain kernel: SELinux: initialized (dev cgroup, type cgroup), uses genfs_contexts
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain kernel: SELinux: initialized (dev rpc_pipefs, type rpc_pipefs), uses genfs_contexts
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain kernel: SELinux: initialized (dev dm-2, type ext4), uses xattr
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Successfully loaded SELinux policy in 289ms 940us.
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Relabelled /dev and /run in 19ms 778us.
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain kernel: SELinux: initialized (dev autofs, type autofs), uses genfs_contexts
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain systemd-journal[454]: Journal started
maj 12 15:57:15 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: systemd 197 running in system mode. (+PAM +LIBWRAP +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +SYSVINIT +LIBCRYP
maj 12 15:57:15 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Set hostname to <localhost.localdomain>.
maj 12 15:57:16 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Apply Kernel Variables.
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Setup Virtual Console.
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started udev Kernel Device Manager.
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain systemd-udevd[446]: starting version 197
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started udev Coldplug all Devices.
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting udev Wait for Complete Device Initialization...
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Show Plymouth Boot Screen...
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Mounted Temporary Directory.
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Mounted POSIX Message Queue File System.
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Mounted Huge Pages File System.
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Mounted Debug File System.
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain kernel: SELinux: initialized (dev tmpfs, type tmpfs), uses transition SIDs
maj 12 15:57:17 localhost.localdomain kernel: SELinux: initialized (dev hugetlbfs, type hugetlbfs), uses transition SIDs
maj 12 15:57:18 localhost.localdomain systemd-modules-load[451]: Inserted module 'uinput'
maj 12 15:57:18 localhost.localdomain kernel: EXT4-fs (dm-2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
maj 12 15:57:18 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Load Kernel Modules.
maj 12 15:57:18 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
maj 12 15:57:18 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Local File Systems (Pre).
maj 12 15:57:18 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Reached target Local File Systems (Pre).
maj 12 15:57:18 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Configure read-only root support...
maj 12 15:57:18 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Import network configuration from initramfs.
maj 12 15:57:18 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Load Random Seed...
maj 12 15:57:18 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Mounting Configuration File System...
maj 12 15:57:18 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Mounted FUSE Control File System.
maj 12 15:57:18 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Mounted Configuration File System.
maj 12 15:57:18 localhost.localdomain kernel: SELinux: initialized (dev configfs, type configfs), uses genfs_contexts
maj 12 15:57:18 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Load Random Seed.
maj 12 15:57:18 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Configure read-only root support.
maj 12 15:57:18 localhost.localdomain kernel: kvm: disabled by bios
maj 12 15:57:18 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Load legacy module configuration.
maj 12 15:57:19 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Show Plymouth Boot Screen.
maj 12 15:57:19 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Forward Password Requests to Plymouth Directory Watch.
maj 12 15:57:19 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Plymouth Directory Watch.
maj 12 15:57:19 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch.
maj 12 15:57:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: asus_wmi: ASUS WMI generic driver loaded
maj 12 15:57:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: asus_wmi: Initialization: 0x0
maj 12 15:57:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: asus_wmi: BIOS WMI version: 0.9
maj 12 15:57:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: asus_wmi: SFUN value: 0x0
maj 12 15:57:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: input: Eee PC WMI hotkeys as /devices/platform/eeepc-wmi/input/input6
maj 12 15:57:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: asus_wmi: Disabling ACPI video driver
maj 12 15:57:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.3: SMBus using PCI Interrupt
maj 12 15:57:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: mei 0000:00:16.0: setting latency timer to 64
maj 12 15:57:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: mei 0000:00:16.0: irq 48 for MSI/MSI-X
maj 12 15:57:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000540-0x000000000000054f SystemIO conflicts with Region \_SB_.PCI0.
maj 12 15:57:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native 
maj 12 15:57:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000530-0x000000000000053f SystemIO conflicts with Region \_SB_.PCI0.
maj 12 15:57:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native 
maj 12 15:57:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000052f SystemIO conflicts with Region \_SB_.PCI0.
maj 12 15:57:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native 
maj 12 15:57:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: lpc_ich: Resource conflict(s) found affecting gpio_ich
maj 12 15:57:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: iTCO_vendor_support: vendor-support=0
maj 12 15:57:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: iTCO_wdt: Intel TCO WatchDog Timer Driver v1.10
maj 12 15:57:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: iTCO_wdt: Found a Cougar Point TCO device (Version=2, TCOBASE=0x0460)
maj 12 15:57:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
maj 12 15:57:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: iTCO_wdt: initialized. heartbeat=30 sec (nowayout=0)
maj 12 15:57:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 49 for MSI/MSI-X
maj 12 15:57:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: ALSA sound/pci/hda/hda_auto_parser.c:306 autoconfig: line_outs=1 (0x1c/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:l
maj 12 15:57:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: ALSA sound/pci/hda/hda_auto_parser.c:310    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
maj 12 15:57:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: ALSA sound/pci/hda/hda_auto_parser.c:314    hp_outs=1 (0x1d/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
maj 12 15:57:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: ALSA sound/pci/hda/hda_auto_parser.c:315    mono: mono_out=0x0
maj 12 15:57:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: ALSA sound/pci/hda/hda_auto_parser.c:318    dig-out=0x20/0x0
maj 12 15:57:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: ALSA sound/pci/hda/hda_auto_parser.c:319    inputs:
maj 12 15:57:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: ALSA sound/pci/hda/hda_auto_parser.c:323      Rear Mic=0x1a
maj 12 15:57:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: ALSA sound/pci/hda/hda_auto_parser.c:323      Front Mic=0x1e
maj 12 15:57:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: ALSA sound/pci/hda/hda_auto_parser.c:323      Line=0x1b
maj 12 15:57:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH Line as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input7
maj 12 15:57:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH Front Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input8
maj 12 15:57:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH Rear Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input9
maj 12 15:57:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input10
maj 12 15:57:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH Line Out as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input11
maj 12 15:57:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: ALSA sound/pci/hda/hda_intel.c:2848 0000:01:00.1: Handle VGA-switcheroo audio client
maj 12 15:57:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: ALSA sound/pci/hda/hda_intel.c:3040 0000:01:00.1: Using LPIB position fix
maj 12 15:57:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: irq 50 for MSI/MSI-X
maj 12 15:57:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: ALSA sound/pci/hda/hda_intel.c:1716 0000:01:00.1: Enable sync_write for stable communication
maj 12 15:57:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: input: HD-Audio Generic HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/c
maj 12 15:57:19 localhost.localdomain kernel: microcode: CPU0 sig=0x206a7, pf=0x2, revision=0x14
maj 12 15:57:20 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Sound Card.
maj 12 15:57:20 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Reached target Sound Card.
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain mtp-probe[569]: checking bus 2, device 3: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2"
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain mtp-probe[568]: checking bus 1, device 4: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2"
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain mtp-probe[565]: checking bus 1, device 3: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1"
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain mtp-probe[566]: checking bus 1, device 5: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3"
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain mtp-probe[565]: bus: 1, device: 3 was not an MTP device
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain mtp-probe[566]: bus: 1, device: 5 was not an MTP device
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain mtp-probe[568]: bus: 1, device: 4 was not an MTP device
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain mtp-probe[569]: bus: 2, device: 3 was not an MTP device
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: sd 4:0:0:2: [sde] Unhandled sense code
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: sd 4:0:0:2: [sde]  
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: sd 4:0:0:2: [sde]  
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: sd 4:0:0:2: [sde]  
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: sd 4:0:0:2: [sde] CDB: 
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 33 00 00 00 08 00
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: blk_update_request: 417 callbacks suppressed
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: end_request: critical target error, dev sde, sector 13056
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: quiet_error: 423 callbacks suppressed
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: Buffer I/O error on device sde, logical block 1632
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: sd 4:0:0:2: [sde] Unhandled sense code
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: sd 4:0:0:2: [sde]  
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: sd 4:0:0:2: [sde]  
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: sd 4:0:0:2: [sde]  
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: sd 4:0:0:2: [sde] CDB: 
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 33 00 00 00 08 00
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: end_request: critical target error, dev sde, sector 13056
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: Buffer I/O error on device sde, logical block 1632
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: sd 4:0:0:2: [sde] Unhandled sense code
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: sd 4:0:0:2: [sde]  
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: sd 4:0:0:2: [sde]  
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: sd 4:0:0:2: [sde]  
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: sd 4:0:0:2: [sde] CDB: 
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 33 d0 00 00 08 00
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: end_request: critical target error, dev sde, sector 13264
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: Buffer I/O error on device sde, logical block 1658
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: sd 4:0:0:2: [sde] Unhandled sense code
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: sd 4:0:0:2: [sde]  
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: sd 4:0:0:2: [sde]  
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: sd 4:0:0:2: [sde]  
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: sd 4:0:0:2: [sde] CDB: 
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 33 d0 00 00 08 00
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: end_request: critical target error, dev sde, sector 13264
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: Buffer I/O error on device sde, logical block 1658
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: sd 4:0:0:2: [sde] Unhandled sense code
maj 12 15:57:21 localhost.localdomain kernel: sd 4:0:0:2: [sde]
```

Comment: In vi I see polish chars

Comment: When I launch gedit from terminal I can write polish charters, but in files I don't see they

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution.

When I opened my file, there was set "Automatycznie wykryte" encoding, which means "automatically detected".

[image]

When I changed it to `UTF-8`, it works correctly. I don't know why, but it's a solution.

[image]